# Create a string with n blank spaces or other repeated character

Tags: ios, string, swift

I want to make a string with *n* blank spaces using Swift, but without using a `for` loop or manually like this:

```
// string with 5-blank space
var s = "      "
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`String` already has a [`repeating:count:` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/2427723-init) just like `Array` (and other collections that adopt the [`RangeReplaceableIndexable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rangereplaceableindexable) protocol):

```
init(repeating repeatedValue: String, count: Int)
```

So you can just call:

```
let spaces = String(repeating: " ", count: 5) // -> "     "
```

Notice that the repeated parameter is a string, not just a character, so you can repeat entire sequences if you want:

```
let wave = String(repeating: "-=", count: 5) // -> "-=-=-=-=-="
```

<sub>*Edit:* Changed to Swift 3 syntax and removed discussion of Swift 1 type ambiguity issues. See the edit history if you need to work with old versions.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 3:

```
var s = String(repeating: " ", count: 5)
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/2427723-init

Answer (score 5):

I think we can play with stringbyPaddingToLength

something like this should work:

```
var str = " ";
var str2 = str.stringByPaddingToLength(20, withString: " ", startingAtIndex: 0);
```

Comment: swift 4.x `str.padding(toLength: 20, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)`

Answer (score 2):

**2022 | SWIFT 3.0 - 5.1:**

I wrote an extension:

```
static func * (str: String, repeatTimes: Int) -> String {
    return String(repeating: str, count: repeatTimes)
}
```

and now you're able to do this by the following way:

```
let tenSpaces = " " * 10
let ab15Times = "ab" * 15
```