# Cannot convert type "Int.Type" to Type "Int" - Function Parameter - Swift Equivalent of setw C++

Tags: swift, function

I've been looking for some equivalent for [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) in swift, and haven't been able to find one. Thus, I've written a quick function that more or less accomplishes the same goal, though when using `toprint` as a parameter, I'm getting a build error saying that `Int.Type` cannot be converted to `Int`. Any idea as to how to fix this?

```
// FUNCTION WITH ERROR
func space (toprint: Int) {
    var spaces = ["        ", "       ", "     ", "    ", "   ", "  ", " "]
    var digits = [Int] ()
    var toprinttemp = toprint
    while toprinttemp >= 1 {
        digits.append(toprint%10)
        toprinttemp = toprinttemp/10
    }

    let count = (digits.count - 1)
    print("(\(spaces[count])", terminator:"")
}

// Print top row
var counter = 0
while (counter) <= (rows - 1) {
    if (tlcorner - counter) <= userinput {
        var toprint:Int = (tlcorner - counter)
        print("\(toprint)", terminator:"")
        // Calling Function
        space(toprint:Int)

    }

    counter += 1
}
```

Comment: Removed the C++ tag because the question is not about C++, but only slightly related.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Don't post a separate comment about why you edited. Specify that comment as part of the edit.

Comment: Why all the extra parentheses in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an `Int` into the function, not the type `Int`.
Call it like this:

```
space(toprint: 5)
```

Note that `toprint` here is the name of the parameter for the `space` function, it is not the `Int` you want to pass in. In your case, you'll want this:

```
space(toprint: toprint)
```

Here the first toprint is the parameter label and the second is the name of your `Int`

---

If your goal is just to get a string with a variable number of spaces, you can just do this:

```
String(repeating: " ", count: 10)
```

Read [Create a string with n blank spaces or other repeated character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806693/create-a-string-with-n-blank-spaces-or-other-repeated-character) for other ways of doing this.

Comment: Thank you! I can't exactly specify the value of toprint, however, as it changes with each loop. Are there any other ways I could go about it?

Comment: I updated my answer after noticing your variable name is also `toprint`. I think you're confusing the parameter label with your `Int` variable.